# input type button onclick function is not working

Tags: javascript

I written an onClick function in input tag type button. But the function is not working when the button clicked.
attaching my input tag and javascript function with this:

```js
function funcBookcar() {
  alert("booking");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="sbmt" align="center" id="sbmt" class="bcar" value="SUBMIT" onClick="funcBookcar()">
```

Comment: <input type="button" name="sbmt" align="center" id="sbmt" class="bcar" value="SUBMIT" onClick="funcBookcar()">

Comment: Can you add your JavaScript code to your question? Your button seems to be fine, so the script may be the issue.

Comment: Use `onclick` instead of `onClick`

Comment: Have you had a look at the developer console (F12)?

Comment: If you are using old doc type `XHTML DOCTYPE` all of your html attributes should be lowercase, so try making it `onclick`. But `onClick` will also work on most browsers

Comment: my javascript function is here:

Comment: why the alert box is not working in my onclick function?

Comment: i tried onclick instead of onClick. But its not working

Comment: Where do you put that js? inside a <script> tag or in a file?

Comment: The code you have in the question works, whatever the problem is, it isn't exposed by the code you've provided.

Comment: @Quentin Is it exposed by adding a working snippet in the question?

Comment: @Fabio_MO — No. Since the snippet works, it doesn't demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you can see in the snippet below your code works so I think you only put the js code in the wrong place.

You have two options:

- Link your javascript file to your html code;
- Write your javascript inside your html code.

```html
<head>
  <!-- 
  Link your code
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/test.js"></script>
  -->
  <script>
  //Write your code in html file
 function funcBookcar() 
 {
   alert("booking");
 }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" name="sbmt" align="center" id="sbmt" class="bcar" value="SUBMIT" onclick="funcBookcar()">
</body>
```

Hope this help :)